# Is every path connected space continuously path connected

Tags: gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, descriptive-set-theory, path-connected

Recall a topological space $X$ is *path connected* if for all $x,y \in X$ there is a continuous function $f\colon [0,1] \to X$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.

Say that $X$ is *continuously path connected* if there is a continuous function $f\colon [0,1] \times X \times X \to X$ such that $f(0,x,y) = x$ and $f(1,x,y) = y$

> Is every Polish path connected space also continuously path connected.

(I'd like to know the answer for Polish spaces, but if it is positive, feel free to mention the answer for larger classes of spaces.)

My guess is that the answer is no, and a counterexample will involve constructing a space with uncountably many "forks in the road" where deciding whether one can go left or right is not continuous in the initial data.  However, I assume something like this has a well-known counterexample, so I am asking it here.

(Feel free to change the tags.  Is this homotopy theory?)

Comment: Typo:  I think you mean $f(0,x,y)$ and $f(1,x,y)$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, oh course!  (I imagine there is a type checking joke somewhere in there, but I am not that witty.)

Comment: Actually I think the answer is already no for extremely nice spaces, e.g. $S^1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Yes, of course you are right.  How silly of me.

Comment: Actually this is true if and only if the space is contactable.

Comment: For completeness' sake, you prove @AntonPetrunin's remark simply by noting that $(t,x) \mapsto f(t,x,y_0)$ is a homotopy between the identity and the constant function with value $y_0$.

Comment: With an extracondition $f(t,x,x)=x$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ and $x\in X$ such spaces are well-known in geometric topology as equi-connected spaces. Equiconnected spaces are contractible and locally contractible. Finite-dimensional metrizable equi-connected spaces are absolute retracts.

Comment: Someone make Petrunin+Antolín-Camarena an actual answer, please...

Comment: This concept of continuous path-connectedness is equivalent to the projections $pr_1,pr_2\colon X\times X\to X$ being homotopic. As Qiaochu Yan writes, this fails for $\mathbb S^1$, for the projections are then distinct non-trivial characters of the torus and so can not be homotopic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by Anton Petrunin, the condition is stated is equivalent to the space being [contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space). Following Omar Antolín-Camarena, this can be seen since $(t,x) \mapsto f(t,x,y_0)$ constitutes a homotopy between the identity on $X$ and the constant function $y_0$, and this is the defining property of contractible spaces.

Contractible spaces are $n$-connected for any $n$, in particular we see that the circle is a very easy example of a path-connected space that is not contractible.

However, I believe that the definition of "continuous path-connected" is not the correct one. Instead, it should be the relativization of the following:

**Definition** Call $X$ effectively path-connected, iff there is a computable multi-valued function $P : X \times X \rightrightarrows  \mathcal{C}([0,1], X)$ where $p \in P(x,y)$ iff $p(0) = x$ and $p(1) = y$.

So every path is a continuous function as it should be, but the way we attach paths to points may be multivalued. Now the circle becomes effectively path-connected, as we can simply non-deterministically decide whether to go round clockwise or counter-clockwise, if our points are closed to $\pi$ apart, and take the direct way otherwise.

It is still not true though that any path-connected space would be effectively path-connected relative to some oracle. For a counterexample, consider the Warsaw circle (described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(topology))). I do not know whether being effectively path-connected relative to some oracle matches some established notion in continuums theory.